# How to change background color of custom keyboard when button is pressed into host app?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, custom-keyboard

I am trying to change my custom keyboard background from host app but some reason it does not work.

I tried `NSUserDefaults` but it doesn't work, here is my code when button is pressed from host app:

```
func buttonTapAction() {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(1, forKey: "abc")
}
```

And this way I am reading values from disk but it always execute else condition:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let abc = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("abc")
    if abc == 1 {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }else{
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241.0/255, green: 235.0/255, blue: 221.0/255, alpha: 1)
    }

    //Other code

}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

[HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Custom-KeyBoard-Demo) is my full project.

Comment: Are you wan to change color from the app and that affect into keyboard?

Comment: yes I want that from my host app.

Comment: Ok I have a solution I post that here just wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enable App Groups for both targets**

Step 1.

[image]

Same steps and group name should be same for NuberWidget Target Keep in mind.

Step 2.

[image]

Step 3.

[image]

Step 4.Code for store value

**Objective C**

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.yourcompany.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults"];

[sharedDefaults setInteger:[self.textField.text integerValue] forKey:@"MyNumberKey"];
[sharedDefaults synchronize];   // (!!) This is crucial.
```

**Swift**

```
let appGroupID = "group.yourcompany.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults"
let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupID)
 defaults.setInteger(1, forKey: "MyNumberKey")
```

Step 5.

**Objective C**

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults"];
    NSString* colornumber= [defaults objectForKey:@"MyNumberKey"];
```

**Swift**

```
let appGroupID = "group.yourcompany.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults"
let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupID)
let number = defaults.integerForKey("MyNumberKey")
```

Step 6. Last but not list is don't forgot to enable "Allow Full Access" Enable.
Goto Keyboard -> info.plist -> NSExtention -> NSExtensionAttributes

[image] 
With this you can solve your problem.

Comment: can you explain this `Same steps and group name should be same for NuberWidget Target Keep in mind`.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni You need to same steps for another for keyboard target

Comment: Then .entitlement file created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81639/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-neon-samuel).